# Get current city name in Graphhopper - Android

Tags: android, location, geocoding, graphhopper

I'm using [Graphopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md) in Android in order to use map and geocoding offline. 
Currently I'm getting the current street name with this code:

```
QueryResult rua = hopper.getLocationIndex().findClosest(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES);
String streetName = rua.getClosestEdge().getName();
```

I found this code after a long search in internet. Is there any documentation for different functions in Graphopper?

I need the same thing for getting the name of current city too. Is there any function for that?

Answer (score 1):

GraphHopper is just a routing engine (no geocoding, no visualization) and therefore has no explicit functionality for (reverse) geocoding.

Comment: Do you know any free library in android for offline reverse geocoding purposes?